# Console not logging after onClick event

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have HTML div that resemble a star rating system.

I'm trying to simple test some javascript so that when I click a star then the console logs 'hello'.

```
<div class=rating>
    <div class="ratings_stars" data-rating="1"></div>
    <div class="ratings_stars" data-rating="2"></div>
    <div class="ratings_stars" data-rating="3"></div>
    <div class="ratings_stars" data-rating="4"></div>
    <div class="ratings_stars" data-rating="5"></div> 
</div>

$('.ratings_stars').on('click', function() {
    console.log('Hello');
});
```

The JS is in a separate file and I've linked that fine.

Comment: Have you included jQuery, and are you wrapping your code inside the DOMReady event?

Comment: Did you include jQuery? Does something alter the elements? Are you referencing the elements before they exist? Learn to debug. `console.log($('.ratings_stars').length)`

Comment: are there any errors in your console?

Comment: @BenM you are the man! Works fine now. Terribly sorry if this was a poor question :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class needs to be in quotes, and place your jQuery listeners in a document ready function:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.ratings_stars').on('click', function() {
    console.log('Hello');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rating">
  <div class="ratings_stars" data-rating="1">Click me</div>
  <div class="ratings_stars" data-rating="2">Click me</div>
  <div class="ratings_stars" data-rating="3">Click me</div>
  <div class="ratings_stars" data-rating="4">Click me</div>
  <div class="ratings_stars" data-rating="5">Click me</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `'` === `"` in this instance.

Comment: This is more elaborate than my answer. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

All sorted.

Needed to wrap in a DOMReady Event.

Thanks for the help everyone.

```
$(function () {
$('.ratings_stars').on('click', function() {
    console.log('Hello');
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use MichaelvE answer for the code. I want to add the following, in your code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.ratings_stars').on('click', function() {
    console.log('Hello');
  });
});
```

The `$(document).ready(function() {/* code to be executed */});` part is necesarry for the DOM to build up. The **DOM** is an in memory tree like representation of an HTML file which we can alter programmatically via JS/JQuery. What JQuery does under the hood is adding an event listener to all all DOM elements which contain the `rating_stars` class.

The JS engine can execute code before the DOM is built up. This will lead to an error because JQuery tries to attach an event handler to a non existing DOM element.